# Setting Sheets Visibility in Excel from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In a workbook I have sheets named `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, etc.

In the "main" sheet, I ask the user to select his/her name out of a list box (Cell D7). In cell D10 the password will be shown. When the password is correct, only the sheet with the name of cell D7 should be visible. All other sheets should stay/be hidden.

I have the following but I could not get it to work.

'Code for Button 2 to unhide the sheet:

```
Sub ViewSheet2()
   pword = Application.InputBox("Type your password", "PASSWORD REQUIRED")
   If pword = Range("D10").Value Then
         Sheets(Range("D7")).Visible = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cell directly to refer to the Value in it

```
Sheets(Cells(7, 4).Value).Visible = True
```

Or if you want to stick to a Range

```
Sheets(Range("D7").Value).Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edited

Try this

```
Sub ViewSheet2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim PWORD As String
pword1 = ws.Range("D7")
PWORD = Application.InputBox("Type your password", "PASSWORD REQUIRED")
If PWORD = ws.Range("D10").value Then
Sheets(Format(pword1)).Visible = True
else
MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `Sheets(Format(pword1)).Visible = xlSheetVisible` and `Sheets(Format(pword1)).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden` - very hidden can only be made visible through VBA and not the menu commands.